# Is there a way to blacklist certain tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Generic Tags like "eos" and "blockchain" serve no real purpose as that is implied for all the pages here.

If these tags don't get removed from posts then we end up with the most popular categories being "eos" and "blockchain" for example.

"smart" and "contract" might be others to consider in favour of "smartcontract", people accidentally create two tags instead of one by using spaces.

Manually having to update questions every time is tedious.

Optimally this admin software provides some sort of tag blacklist where we can add these.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. We typically block the name and primary subject of the site automatically. I've also had `eos` and `blockchain` removed and blocked.

(Editors! This action left **4 `untagged` questions** which will need to be retagged properly)

Mistaken tags like `smart` and `contract` are handled in a different way. I will  fix those tags now (by renaming them). Once properly set, the text completion *should* guide the user to the correct tag:

<kbd>s</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> → <kbd>smart-contract</kbd>

If someone inadvertently re-creates those tags anyway, simply edit them in place to keep the tags correct. Unused tags are deleted automatically (typically within 24 hours). Once we get out of private beta (hopefully in about 3 weeks), the reputation/experience needed to create NEW tags increases automatically, so the problem generally takes care of itself.

Comment: Related: [How can we allow eosjs tag, but forbid eos?](https://eosio.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-can-we-allow-eosjs-tag-but-forbid-eos)