# How can we allow eosjs tag, but forbid eos?

Tags: support, tagging

Currently when I'm trying to add an `eosjs` tag to a question, StackExchange says

`eos tag is not allowed`

How can we allow `eosjs` tag?

Comment: I suppose only moderators can do so as the tags are too similar

Comment: it's super important, I just tried to create a question about eosjs and it didn't allow me.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to add an `eosjs` tag, so please take a moment and retag the questions missing that label as appropriate. Thank you.